# Find all the pairs in the array that match the condition

Tags: algorithms

Problem:

We have an `int array[n]`. We need to find all the pairs for which `array[a] + array[b] = 0`.

The only algorithm I came up with so far has `O(n^2)` - tho most obious one. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Sure, store every value you touch in a hash table and whenever you encounter `x`, check whether you have `-x` somewhere. Takes only linear time.

Comment: If you consider the extreme case of half the array being -1 the other half +1, you get n^2/4 results, so there isn't a way around quadratic runtime, unless you're willing to use some kind of implicit output form (e.g. a pair of sets which is understood as the Cartesian product of these sets).

Comment: @CodesInChaos I agree with your conclusion, but the most extreme case would be all values 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort your array, but maintain the original index number. Then you can loop through it once, each value can be instantly matched with the set of indexes stored against the matching point.

ie. loop through your array and store a key-value pair (where the key is array[n] and the value is n). A single iteration of this container will show you all matching indexes for the current value.

Comment: I am not sure if I get this correctly. So, when iterating over this container i simply take the key (number) and check if the container contains the opposite key (opposite number), then just simply multiply their values and add it to "pair counter" variable?

Comment: Yes. You have to keep track of multiple entries in each kv pair (ie its a key to multiple-values) then the pairs you want are the initial key matched to all entries in the matching key. You can only multiply the values if you are only keeping track of the quantity of pairs that equal zero (but in this case, you don't need to track the array indexes, just a count of each value)